# Retrieve the content of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a window, with an iframe in it.
When i clicking a button, then the iframe will load (loaded from a web site).
Is it possible to retrieve the content of that iframe? How can I retrieve the content of that page?

I can view the source code by left clicking iframes View Source.

I need to store the source in a DB.

1.
var iframe = document.getElementById("ifrm");

alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML );

2.alert(window.frames['ifrm'].document.body.innerHTML);

these two comments are showing "access denied" error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (if it's on the same domain):

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

Note that you need to make sure the frame has been loaded completely before you run this code. Otherwise, you will get strange exceptions.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.

Here's the google query I used: [google query](http://www.google.com/search?q=iframe+get+content)

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not possible to read the contents of an iframe loaded from another server, due to the [same origin security policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). However, it looks like you want to store the content on the server anyway, so why not request the content from the server?

Comment: You are right, I wrote mostly gibberish. Tried to clear it up. Better now?